# Why does my databases folder show loading...?

Tags: android-studio

[image: picture from Android Studio]

I put a database in my databases folder (in assets) earlier and I could see it.
After updating Android Studio, when I click on the databases folder, it just shows "loading..." and it never goes away. I cannot see any file names.
I would not care except I updated my database and tried to copy it in again and it does not do anything.
(I copy the database and paste it in the folder. The pop-up to name the file comes up. I hit OK and the database does not change. Also, it still says "loading...")

Comment: is that directory contains images? if that so restart android studio and see

Comment: no images, just my database. I tried restarting, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. I had to disable SQLite plugin 1.4.1